# Is there a better way to get all availability zones for all regions?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

When configuring the lightsail client, it asks me to provide a region, if I don't provide a region, requests don't go through.

However, providing a region only gives me availability zones associated with that region even though the code gives me all regions anyways. If this were the case, it would make more sense to just provide the client's region in the response, but I get them all which is odd that it is not consistent with the data provided in terms of availability zones. Here is the below code that I'm testing to retrieve the availability zones which I plan to store and use at a further point in the application.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("[redacted]", "[redacted]");
AmazonLightsailClient client = new AmazonLightsailClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var response = await client.GetRegionsAsync(new GetRegionsRequest() { IncludeAvailabilityZones = true});

foreach (Region currentRegion in response.Regions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Region {currentRegion.Name} - {currentRegion.AvailabilityZones.Count} availability zones");
}
```

The output is shown below

- Region us-east-1 - 6 availability zones
- Region us-east-2 - 0 availability zones
- Region us-west-2 - 0 availability zones
- Region eu-west-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region eu-west-2 - 0 availability zones
- Region eu-west-3 - 0 availability zones
- Region eu-central-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region ap-southeast-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region ap-southeast-2 - 0 availability zones
- Region ap-northeast-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region ap-northeast-2 - 0 availability zones
- Region ap-south-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region ca-central-1 - 0 availability zones
- Region eu-north-1 - 0 availability zones

Without having to resort to looping through all RegionEndpoints and instantiating a new client in that Region, is there a way I can just get all availability zones when it provides all Regions or am I going to have to waste 1 API call per region to get this data?

Comment: Does the `Region` not have an `availabilityZones` array you can iterate through? See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/2016-11-28/api-reference/API_Region.html)

Comment: That is what I'm referring to. It's a List<AvailabilityZone>, however, only the first Region's AvailabilityZones object is populated. If you look in my original code block, I just printed out the counts of the AvailabilityZones Lists for a high level view.

Comment: I wonder if its only returning back the zones of the region your credentials are tied to.  Any way you can test that and see (change regions/use different credentials)?

Comment: I know I can iterate over the different regions and make a new client and get that region's data. My credentials are currently allowing all regions. However, if I loop through all regions and make a new client with that region, I end up spending another API call on my quota. For example, I switch my region to USWest2 when instantiating the AmazonLightsailClient, I will then lose all AvailabilityZone elements in USEast1 and get only USWest2 AvailabilityZones. Which would be highly inefficient in managing API calls

Comment: There is no charge for API calls, nor could I find any API quotas on [Amazon Lightsail endpoints and quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lightsail.html). So, don't worry about making multiple API calls.

Comment: I'd find it odd to see no API throttling on Lightsail when EC2 has defined throttling limits. I'll run some tests to see if it can be tested, however, adjusting the algorithm in the meantime to establish new clients and get them all adds an additional 15 seconds of runtime to this one function, which is vastly terrible.

Comment: Update: I have done the above and used Parallel.ForEach instead of a normal for each loop and was able to get it down to 2 seconds. However, it is still vastly uncomfortable for me to commit that to the code base. Hopefully some thinking on it over the weekend might come up with some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the region in your api client settings. This is a different SDK to yours, but equivalent to your C++ version.

```
  $client= new $class([
     'profile' => 'default',
     'region' => us-east-1,
     'version' => 'latest',
  ]);
```

and when you call using either:
$result = $client->describeAvailabilityZones();
or
$result = $client->getRegions([]);

You'll get visibility and access to the availability zones in that region.

**Unfortunately it's not possible to get a list or create instances, without changing the api client's region.**

If you're just looking to get a complete list for reference, you'll have to loop the call, changing the region based on the known set of regions you have enabled for your account (as not all AWS regions are automatically enabled).

Comment: This does not answer my question. I don’t even know what language you’ve written that in. My current C# code already allows me to enumerate and query on a by-region basis. I would just like a list of all zones where I do one API call. There’s no reason for me to just change languages to do the same thing.

Comment: There is no solution in the AWS API that returns all the availability zones for all the regions. I use a different SDK than you, but the endpoints are the same. So irrespective of what SDK you use (C,Java,PHP, whatever), the only option is looping through the REGIONs in your AmazonLightsailClient client = new AmazonLightsailClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1). ie. You currently have **USEast1** in your client arguments, so the AWS API will only return availability zones in this region. You need to change this to USWest1 to get a list of us-west-1 availability zones, etc

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed your earlier comment about the looping and I get your frustration. But AWS doesn't automatically give access to all regions. There are a bunch that are disabled, and these trickle down to IAM policies, etc. Plus customers from different regions may not have access to all regions. I can only guess that's why they've put hard constraints on the the Availability Zone queries. I've looked into this myself, but because results for this type of query are set to your client-region, it seems like an intentional limit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about LightSail but you can use the SDK to do these EC2 Commands to query all Regions (some regions have null for AZ Count, either they're under construction or something has changed with the API):

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].{RegionName:RegionName, AvailabilityZoneCount:AvailabilityZoneCount}'
```

> [
> {
> "RegionName": "ap-south-1",
> "AvailabilityZoneCount": null
> },
> {
> "RegionName": "eu-north-1",
> "AvailabilityZoneCount": null
> },
> {
> "RegionName": "eu-west-3",

Then query individual Regions to get info about the Zones (I'm using ap-southeast-2):

```
 aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-southeast-2 --query 'AvailabilityZones[*].{ZoneName:ZoneName}'
```

> [
> {
> "ZoneName": "ap-southeast-2a"
> },
> {
> "ZoneName": "ap-southeast-2b"
> },
> {
> "ZoneName": "ap-southeast-2c"
> } ]

Tested:

[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question. My current C# code already allows me to enumerate and query on a by-region basis. I would just like a list of all zones where I do one API call. There’s no reason for me to adapt my code to translate through the command line standard output to do the same thing I’m currently doing.